# Rules engines for CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, rules, rule-engine

What are some some of the most scalable Rules engines for CodeIgniter?

Comment: Try this one from Swindle. Sounds promising:
[http://www.swindle.net/php-rules/](http://www.swindle.net/php-rules/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is also far too much of a vague to get any real answers.

I'm not aware of any specifically for CI - it's just a framework.

You would need to design a business rule engine that would fit your requirements and budget etc, and implement it within the CI framework.

Personally (again depending on your situation) I'd just build any rules in to the various models my app may use, given that most business rules are something like:

```
if($some_condition)
{
    $do->something();
}
```

which would fit quite easily in to a model with minimal effort.